# How to create call graph for c/c++ code in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, call-graph, call-flow

I have read on internet that cdt is basically used for generating call graphs for c/c++ code in eclipse.
I have installed eclipse juna's latest version along with the MinGW and cygwin to compile and run c/c++ code. My question is do I have to install cdt again along with the eclipse version. I already have option of creating cdt project under my eclipse new tab. Also how is the call graph generated in eclipse. Basically steps are needed for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CDT to see dependencies between functions, but if you really want comprehensive call graphs you are better off installing [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), which is very well supported by CDT and Eclipse in general.